# how you handle payload entity size too large on vercel?

Tags: vercel

I want to upload images and got this error:

```
PAYLOAD_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE
```

I have read the limits and saw the accept size is until 4.5MB
So how you deal with it ? is there any way to get around that ?